# "Solutions offered" or "offered solutions"?

Tags: phrases, word-order

Which of these two is more grammatically correct?

> 1. Defining customer needs and advising on **solutions offered**.
> 2. Defining customer needs and advising on **offered solutions**.

Comment: It's really just a matter of opinion. My opinion is I'd prefer option #1 above if I had to pick one or the other, but if I were writing it myself I wouldn't use "offered" at all. I'd either not bother with anything in that "slot", or go for *...advising on **recommended** solutions*. Just don't ask me why I'd invariably put "offered" *after* the noun, but "recommended" *before* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is actually short for "solutions that have been offered". So it's correct.

In the second sentence you use offered as adjective, but it's a verb, a participle to be precise. Participles often can be used as adjectives. Lost, excited or advanced are perfect examples.

Others have to be used with care:

- the shoe left vs. the left shoe
- the man concerned vs. the concerned man

FumbleFinger suggested to use "recommended" and would put it before "solutions". Mind the difference: Recommended solutions could be solutions that are generally regarded as good (= good solutions, solutions recommended by everyone) whereas the solutions offered are most likely the solutions that are offered by you. So I'd definitely go with the first sentence.